# gtest unexpected conversion

Tags: c++, googletest

I am testing the correct operation of my function

```
bool Core::IsMeta(void)
{
  return mProc->GetCode(mPC)->Meta;
}
```

using instructions

> ```
> EXPECT_EQ(true,CC->IsMeta()); // The instruction pointed to is meta
> EXPECT_EQ(false,CC1->IsMeta()); // The instruction pointed to is NOT meta
> ```

the tests run OK, but the two tests behave differently: the 'true' case compiles OK, the 'false' case presents with the warning

> In file included from
>   /... ./build/gtest/src/gtest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1929:0,
>                    from /... .cpp:1:
>   /... .cpp:
>   In member function ‘virtual void
>   ... ::TestBody()’:
>   /... /build/gtest/src/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:133:55:
>   warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type for argument 1 of ‘char
>   testing::internal::IsNullLiteralHelper(testing::internal::Secret*)’
>   [-Wconversion-null]
>        (sizeof(::testing::internal::IsNullLiteralHelper(x)) == 1)
>                                                          ^

Why gtest wants to convert 'false' to pointer? And why not 'true'?
Do I miss something?

Comment: why do you not use `EXPECT_TRUE` and `EXPECT_FALSE` for boolean tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For booleans you need to use `EXPECT_TRUE()` and `EXPECT_FALSE()` rather than `EXPECT_EQ`.

Comment: Does not explain what is happening. Why doesn't eq work for bools?

Comment: @The Badger: I just copied lines of test above the test line in question. Yes, I can use EXPECT_TRUE(), etc. I think, however, that eq should work, too. And, I also find it strange that 'false' provokes a very strange conversion, while 'true' works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with gtest, it is actually a gcc bug as stated [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/322#issuecomment-125645145).